# Rust mocking `std::process::Child` for test?

Tags: testing, rust, mocking

I have an application that spawns a long running [`Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) process. I want to test the logic of the application and the child struct is not really needed for this, I've looked at several mocking frameworks like mockall or faux. But can't really see how I could mock a simple external struct? Any help are really appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help if you could add a little bit of demo code on how you use `Child` in your application. In general, I suspect that you don't need a framework at all and could get away with a simple trait `ChildProcess` that you implement for a newtype of Child and for your mock type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to replace the behavior of `std::process::Command` and `std::process::Child` outright. However, there is a way to change what actually happens — change the command that is executed!

1. Modify your code so that there is some way to configure (“dependency inject”) the path of the child process. (This might also be useful in non-test scenarios!)
2. Create the file `src/bin/test-child.rs` whose `main()` function has whatever behavior you want the test child to have.
3. In your test code (which must be located in `tests/`, an “integration test”, not within the application code), pass `env!("CARGO_BIN_EXE_test-child")` as the path to the program the code under test should spawn. ([This environment variable is set automatically by Cargo.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html))

Taking this approach, instead of an in-process mock, means that your test can be more realistic; it does not call a mock that might be subtly different from `std`, but in fact starts a real process. The required configuration might also be useful when packaging/deploying your application, since it allows complying with requirements about where the child program must be stored, or selecting a different version at run time.

Comment: yes I thought of this and thank you for the extensive answer. In the end I ended up re-writing my code so that it takes optionals instead. As a veteran Java developer I feel this is quite invasive and harder to do clean code in, it might be the lack of experience.

Comment: @NinoMartinezWael This is of course subjective, but my own perspective as a veteran Java developer is that I've spent a lot of time fixing test code that broke because it uses mocks whose behavior doesn't correctly implement the interface. Therefore, I'll always choose to avoid mocks in favor of configuring the real thing to work in a test, or if that's too heavyweight, a fake. But *all* of these choices still require injecting the test object/configuration somehow — you can't and shouldn't avoid having a means to explicitly configure the thing you want to replace with a test double.